# rpc/rpc.h file not found on windows

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, sunrpc

I am working on sunrpc library developed by Sun Microsystems on windows.

I have downloaded GnuWin32 sunrpc4.0 on windows 10.

I am running rpcgen -a -C -Y "C:/MinGW/bin" add.x command and I am able to get .c , .h and Makefile  files.

Now I am compiling using make -f Makefile. I am getting following error "fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory"

I have installed "rpcsvc-proto" package from cygwin tool. My rpc.h file location is C:/cygwin64/usr/include/rpc/rpc.h. I have included this path into environmental variables. Still I am getting this file not found error.

I have made following changes to my Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS += -g -DRPC_SVC_FG
LDLIBS += -lnsl 
RPCGENFLAGS =
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do NOT mix Cygwin libraries and Mingw build. Use Cygwin library only for Cygwin build

Comment: @matzeri, I tried to run my code from cygwin shell. Now error for #include<rpc/rpc.h> is solved. Thanks to you. But now I am getting different error for LDLIBS:                                                                                            
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lnsl: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile.ipg_rpc:41: ipg_rpc_client] Error 1" How to deal with this? any idea? In my Makefile LDLIBS = -lnsl is written.

Answer (score 0):

There is a portable implementation of XDR which comes with `rpc/rpc.h` at [http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/portablexdr/](http://people.redhat.com/%7Erjones/portablexdr/)

I was able to build it with MinGW-w64 with some tweaks, see: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/portablexdr.winlib